# Настроить ActionSheet на ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос: 
На моем ViewController есть выпадающая таблица сверху (TableView - создана программно). Таблица заполнена данными. При нажатии на какое-либо значение из таблицы мне нужно вызвать `ActionSheet` (я реализовал его в методе *didSelectRowAtIndexPath*). Проблема в том, что таблица находится как бы за `ViewController`, и когда происходит событие `ActionSheet`, то его не видно (на скрине видна суть проблемы). Как мне вызвать `ActionSheet` на `ViewController` или может подскажите другой вариант создания `ActionSheet`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE 1:
Пробовал использовать bringSubviewToFront и sendSubviewToBack, но ничего из это не вышло

UPDATE 2:

Нашел проблему: При создании tableView программно, я использовал следующий код:

```
     let menuController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
         menuController.view = self
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = menuController
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.addSubview(ViewController.view)
```

Поэтому все мои Alert попадали на TableView. Для исправление нужно изменить код следующим образом:

```
     let menuController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
         menuController.view = self
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.addSubview(menuController.view)
```

Answer (score 1):

с версии iOS 8.3 нужно использовать UIAlertController:

```
 UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                           message:@"This is an alert."
                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

 UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

 [alert addAction:defaultAction];
```

показывайте на самом переднем controller-e

```
 [controller presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

если ваш search контроллер не в вашем ViewController классe,  используйте delegation,чтобы передать событие  из метода didSelectRowAtIndexPath в ваш класс ViewController  и там вызвать метод

```
       [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**SWIFT**

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My Alert", message: "My Alert", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

 let defaultAcation = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
     // ...
 }

 alertController.addAction(defaultAcation)

  controller.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
      // ...
 }
```